# Cannot manage associations in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Post` model which is used to store content posted by guest users, and that content is managed by an Admin user. The admin has the rights to block or unblock a particular post.

What I want to do is this:

1. Display all unblocked Posts to the Guest Users.
2. Display all Posts to the admin user.

For the first requirement, I have a model `BlockedPost` which has a polymorphic association with `Post` model. The post that will be blocked by the admin will be maintained in the `BlockedPost` model.

For the second requirement I have to give admin the right to block or unblock any particular content. So in my `posts/index.html.erb` I have done this

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% post.content %>
  <% if post.post_blocked? %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Unblock', blocked_post_path(content.id),:method => :delete%></td>
  <% else %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Block', create_blocked_post_path(content.id) %></td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The `post_blocked?` method above is defined in the Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def post_blocked?
    !self.blocked_posts.nil?
  end
end
```

This works but the problem is every time the `post_blocked?` method is called it makes a database call.

Is there any way to stop this behavior and get the status of all posts in one database call itself?

Comment: the "NEED HELP" is implied when you pose the question; you may get some sour glances if you put that in the title of your post.

Answer (score 1):

hmm... i think you should change your models a little, because they are unconfortable a bit and there isnt any fast way to get your posts from DB,
delete BlockedPost model
and add a column to Post model (in migration)
`t.boolean :blocked, :default => true`
I'd do it like this:

```
@blocked_posts = Post.where( :blocked => false)
@unblocked_posts = Post.where( :blocked => true )
```

or prepare scopes in your Post model
and then in your view just display 2 lists

```
<% @unblocked_posts.each do |upost| %>
  <%= upost.content %>
  <%= link_to 'Block that post', ... %>
<% end %>
<% @blocked_posts.each do |bpost| %>
  <%= bpost.content %>
  <%= link_to 'Unblock', ... %>
<% end %>
```